# How do I catch error and write to strerr with letting the program break

Tags: python, stderr

Let's say I have a program that runs continuously, waiting for order from a program with standard input. The method that keeps waiting for order is called "run" using while.

[image]

As you see, when run() gets certain order, they pass the order to certain function.

When I run the program, every time I give a command that can cause an error (say: Index error), it breaks and shut down (obviously)

I decided to try to catch the error with `try/except`

```
def a(order):
    try:
        <some algorithm>
        return something
    except Exception, error:
        stderr.write(error)
        stderr.flush()
def b(order):
    try:
        <some algorithm>
        return something
    except Exception, error:
        stderr.write(error)
        stderr.flush()
def run(order)
    while stdin.notclosed:
        try:
            read stdin
            if stdin==specific order :
                x=a(stdin order)
            else:
                x=b(stdin order)
        except Exception,error:
            stderr.write(error)
            stderr.flush()
run()
```

However, it seems the program that gives the order can't read the error. From my analyst, it seems the program that gives order only start reading `stderr` after the program that reads the order ends. However, due to `try/catch`, the program never ends. Is there anyway that to catch the error, write it, then end it. (The error can came from any function)

PS: Let's assume you can't modify or read the program that gives order. (This is competition, the reason I said this, is since that when I access the `stderr`, it's empty.)

Comment: you want to capture the error and stop execution or you want to capture which function caused the error and stop execution.

Comment: Can you run this program once per order (get rid of the `while`), hence giving your untouchable parent the opportunity to read `stderr` each time? Does your parent read `stdout`, or is it the same as `stderr`? If not, is it watching files? How does it expect to be notified of errors?

Comment: You can end an `except` suite with a `raise` statement to re-raise the last exception that was active.

Comment: @Anurag I'd like to capture the error and stop the execution. Like just stops when you don't have any error exception.

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn, unfortunately, I have no idea about the program that gives the order (due to competition), but I can tell you the program doesn't read the stderr (just the stdout), so when a error comes, I can download the stderr in a txt. (They once told me that the stderr has nothing to do with the program). My program unfortunately, must run all the time.

Comment: @martineau Can you elaborate it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this does what you need, but you could re-raise the exception being handled by adding an empty`raise`statement at the end of the`except`block as shown below. This will either cause the exception to be handled by the next higher-up`try/except`block, if there is one, or terminate the program if there isn't.

Example:

```
def a(order):
    try:
        <some algorithm>
        return something
    except Exception, error:
        stderr.write(error)
        stderr.flush()
        raise  # re-raise exception
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def a(order):
        try:
            <some algorithm>
            return something
        except Exception, error:
           import traceback
           trace = traceback.format_exc()
           return trace

    def b(order):
        try:
            <some algorithm>
            return something
        except Exception, error:
           import traceback
           trace = traceback.format_exc()
           return trace

    def run(order)
        while stdin.notclosed:
            try:
                read stdin
                if stdin==specific order :
                    x=a(stdin order)
                else:
                    x=b(stdin order)
                #check if x == trace then sys.exit()
            except Exception,error:
                stderr.write(error)
                stderr.flush()
    run()
```